# How to report that custom (added) Calculated Property of entity object has changed?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-binding, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

First, I apologize for my low level English writing.

I use Entity Framework and data-binding in WPF MVVM project.
I would like to know what is the best way to do data binding to added calculated property of EntityObject which is generated with Entity Framework.

For example:

```
partial class Person
{
    partial string Name...

    partial string Surname...

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return Name + Surname; }
    }
}
```

And then in XAML something like ...Text="{Binding FullName, Mode=Twoway}"

At this point my GUI doesn't know when property FullName is changed... how can I notify it? 
I've tried with ReportPropertyChanged but it return's an error...

Also, I wonder what is the best way to implement binding when one binding depends on more properties...calculated properties or value converters or something different?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562738/notify-one-object-when-a-property-of-another-object-changes

Comment: Thanks for reply, 
I know for PropertyChanged event, but I don't know how to use it within Entity Framework generated class...because there is already implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged on EntityObject class (ReportPropertyChanged event), but I can't use is, it trows an error...

Answer (score 2):

You could subscribe to the PropertyChanged event in the constructor and if the property name matches either of the two source properties, raise the event for the calculated one.

```
public Person()
{
    this.PropertyChanged += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "Name" || e.PropertyName == "Surname") OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
        };
}
```

Comment: Tnx for reply, I've done something similar, but it appears that I can't use ReportPropertyChanged on calculated property, i.e. property that is not mapped...it throws an error...

Comment: True, use just OnPropertyChanged then, the user interface will react just fine. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are looking for this kind of thing:

```
public string FullName
{
    get { return Name + Surname; }
    set 
    {
        // You should do some validation while and before splitting the value
        this.Name = value.Split(new []{' '})[0];
        this.Surname = value.Split(new []{' '})[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this solves the wrong problem. When somebody changes just the `Surname`, he needs a way to notify clients that the `FullName` has changed.